# Set of Least Common Ancestors in a Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, lowest-common-ancestor

I have a hierarchy of nodes that I need to use for an analysis. Sort of like this

[image]

I'm trying to find an algorithm that will allow me to find the nearest common ancestors between two nodes. I know there are algorithms that find the lowest common ancestor, but I haven't been able to find one that allows us to find the nearest few.

For example, in the picture I linked above, if I give it two nodes: 0 and 1, it should return 2 and 5. i.e. It should return all common ancestors of the nodes that don't have descendants that are also common ancestors. A naive approach would be to get all the common ancestors of 0 and 1: {7, 5, 6, 3, 2}, and then eliminate 7 since it has descendants in the set. Then it'll eliminate 6 and 3 as well. So it would return SLCA = {5,2}. At the moment, I've stored all the ancestors of each node in a list. So this naive approach is possible. However, I'd like do a more efficient method that will be scalable for even very large graphs. Ultimately, for a given graph, I'd like to be able to compute the pairwise SLCA of each pair of nodes. I think this brute force approach would be slow for very large graphs.

Does anyone know of such an algorithm? I've been reading these papers, but they are pretty dense, and I've been stuck trying to understand them.

https://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~czumaj/PUBLICATIONS/DRAFTS/LCA-Max-witness.pdf

http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/dherman/browse/projects/mini-javac/papers/bender01finding.pdf

https://algo2.iti.kit.edu/download/fischer10new.pdf

https://algo2.iti.kit.edu/download/fischer10new.pdf

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well actually your "brute force" algorithm is quite efficient. Let's analyze it:

Finding all of the common ancestors, you can do this with two BFS and an array that keep the node which are in both trees: Time - `O(V + E)`, Memory: `O(V)`.

Now you can find all of the ancestors which do not have descendants in the group, which are all the nodes that are the closest to the roots. This will not take long, take the sub graph of this group and find a node with no incoming edges in `O(V + E)` time (By iterating over the nodes), and `O(V)` memory. This will be your answer.

So in total - Time `O(V + E)`, Memory `O(V)`.

> The next answer is not the correct answer, it finds the closest common ancestor (I have written it by mistake and I don't really want to delete it):

Duplicate the graph, now we have `G1` and `G2`. For each node in `G1` create a new edge over to the corresponding node in `G2`. 'Flip' all the edges in `G2` - if there was an edge from `v` to `u` now it's from `u` to `v`.

Call this new graph `G`, call the two nodes you need to find the SLCA `u` and `v`.

It is easy to show that the shortest route from `u` in `G1` to the corresponding `v` in `G2` will pass through an edge from `G1` to `G2` and that the node of this edge (both nodes on this edge are corresponding) will be in the SLCA group.
That is since if you look at the original graph, the paths we took from each node `v`, `u` is the shortest to meet, which is the definition of the SLCA group.

Now you need to find all the path of the shortest path length and extract all of these nodes.

Time: `O(E + V)` (shortest path - BFS)
Memory: `O(V)` (BFS)

Comment: Thank you so much!. Is there a paper I can can access that explain this? I'd like to see the theory behind it.

Comment: You're welcome. No, there is no paper, I just thought of it now...

Comment: OK. I was asking because I wanted to make sure that it was rigorously proven that this will, in fact give us the SLCA, every time.

Comment: OK, I'm not quite sure this will work. Let's say that the nodes in G2 are 0', 1',... and that if (0,2) is an edge in G1, then (2',0') is an edge in G2. In the example, I gave, your method does seem to work. It'll see that there are two paths of shortest length = 3, between 0 and 1. However, if we split edge (0,5) in G1, into 10 edges by adding some in-and-out nodes. Then the shortest path from 0 to 1' would only return SLCA = {2}. However, I still want it to return SLCA = {5,2] at this point since 5 is a common ancestor which doesn't have descendants that are common ancestors.

Comment: The issue with this answer is that "lowest" in the sense of lowest common ancestor doesn't mean "shortest" in the sense of shortest path.

Comment: Yes you are correct @kaya3 , I have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @ZuhaibAhmed edited. Please look at the solution now.

Comment: Thank You! I'll just stick to the brute force algorithm